# Trouble installing s2geometry on a GCP App Machine

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

**Hey everyone,**

I recently started using [s2geometry](https://github.com/google/s2geometry) on my own computer and environment and everything was great. The problem is that I am now trying to use my code on a google cloud App Engine and I ran into an error that I do not know how to resolve when installing s2geometry.

Here is what I did :

```
mkdir s2geo
cd s2geo
git clone https://github.com/google/s2geometry.git
cd s2geometry
mkdir build
cd build
cmake \
            -DGTEST_ROOT=/home/path_to_googletest \
            -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
            -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m \
            -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so ..
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

At first I had some problem while doing because the python executable was python2 hence all of the flags.
With those flags I did not run into any problem while doing so however whenever I try to import s2 I run into the following error :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__pywraps2)
```

From what I understand it is an error coming from the fact that Python is loading a module from a compiled *.so file instead of from a *.py file. The error is caused by the *.so files being linked against Python 2 libraries instead of Python 3 libraries. Or at least that's what I found here : https://github.com/pytorch/ELF/issues/98

So my questions are : What am I doing wrong ? Is it a problem of Python 2 being the default Python interpreter ? What flag do I have to mention to install the module correctly.

Thank you very much.

## EDIT :

Following [@Tim Trewartha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6700493/tim-trewartha) comment, I tried to dig how I managed to successfully install s2geometry and I believe I used this dockerfile (not quite sure given how old it is).

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV BASE_S2_DIR="/root/s2geometry" \
    WORK_DIR="/root/work"

#
# install system-level dependencies
#
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
                    git \
                    libgflags-dev \
                    libgeos++-dev \
                    libgoogle-glog-dev \
                    libgtest-dev \
                    libproj-dev \
                    libssl-dev \
                    swig \
                    vim

RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.17.2/cmake-3.17.2-Linux-x86_64.sh \
      -q -O /tmp/cmake-install.sh \
      && chmod u+x /tmp/cmake-install.sh \
      && mkdir /usr/bin/cmake \
      && /tmp/cmake-install.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr/bin/cmake \
      && rm /tmp/cmake-install.sh

ENV PATH="/usr/bin/cmake/bin:${PATH}"
# create convenience link for python to default to python3 (obviously)
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

#
# build, test and install google s2geometry (c++) with SWIG python bindings
#
RUN git clone https://github.com/google/s2geometry.git ${BASE_S2_DIR}

WORKDIR ${BASE_S2_DIR}/build

RUN cmake -D GTEST_ROOT=/usr/src/gtest \
          -D WITH_GFLAGS=ON \
          -D WITH_GLOG=ON \
          -D PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars; d=get_config_vars(); print('/usr/lib/{}/{}'.format(d['MULTIARCH'], d['INSTSONAME']))") \
          -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
          -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=$(which python) \
          -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
          -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
          ..

RUN make \
  && make install

# create convenience "s2" module link for SWIG python bindings to s2geometry
RUN DIST_PACKAGES_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
  && ln -s ${DIST_PACKAGES_DIR}/pywraps2.py ${DIST_PACKAGES_DIR}/s2.py

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN apt-get -y install python3-venv
```

Comment: I'm not able to install s2geometry on my WSL instance on python 3.10. No idea why it just won't install. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Just edited my post with a new Dockerfile @TimTrewartha